# C# How to share authentication/authorization cookie between projects?

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, microservices, openid

It's a rather question related with conceptual approach.

So I have two projects - in one the Authentication is already implemented and working ok. It's a .net core SPA with OpenID + Cookie (without without ASP.NET Core Identity).

The second project is the REST API that I want to use that cookie to Authorize some of the endpoints so basically SSO.

The biggest challenge to me is I don't know how I should modify second project to "accept" the cookie from first one - I need at least some starting point.

This one is not helping at all: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0
It's not clear from documentation what I need to do in **both** projects to make it work.

So what I'm thinking is to copy-paste the `services.AddAuthentication(...)` from first project to the second one so they can share same `Authority` - I believe there is no other way that second project knows that cookie is "ours" cookie?

**Update:**
Here I'm giving code samples - with setup below it keeps trying to redirect me to login as don't treat it's authenticated:

**Project A (where user login and we want "generate" cookie for this and other projects):**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie.Name = "test";
            options.Cookie.Domain = ".localhost";
            options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "xxx";
            options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
            options.MetadataAddress = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?appid=xxx";
            options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0";
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                NameClaimType = "name"
            };
        });

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("/cookies"))
        .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "test";
        options.Cookie.Domain = ".localhost";
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    });
    
}
```

**Project B (REST API - here we wan't just to "consume" cookie generated in Project A):**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "test";
        options.Cookie.Domain = ".localhost";
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("/cookies"))
        .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "test";
        options.Cookie.Domain = ".localhost";
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
}
```

**Error I'm getting:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you referenced actually has everything you need. But it requires some basic knowledge to understand that. To use the cookie set by one app in another you need to ensure two things:

1. The cookie should be sent to both app
   1.1. If apps hosted on the same domain but on different paths, you need to [set cookie `Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#share-cookies-across-different-base-paths) to the common denominator. For example, here the common denominator is `/`:
   https://my-domain.com/app1
   https://my-domain.com/app2
   Here is `/api` (but `/` is also valid)
   https://my-domain.com/api/app1
   https://my-domain.com/api/app2
   1.2 If apps hosted on different domains, they **must** be subdomains of some common domain. [Set cookie domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#share-cookies-across-subdomains) to the common domain value to share it between subdomains.
   For example, here the common domain is `.company.com`:
   https://sub-domain1.company.com
   https://sub-domain2.company.com
   This is also example of common domain `.company.com`
   https://company.com
   https://sub-domain2.company.com
   But these 2 domains **can't share** cookies because they don't have common domain:
   https://sub-domain1.company1.com
   https://sub-domain2.company2.com
   1.3 You can also mix domain and path configuration if your apps hosted on different domains with common sub-domain and different path. For example, here the domain should be `.company.com` and path `/`:
   https://sub-domain1.company.com/api/app1
   https://sub-domain2.company.com/app2
2. Both app can decrypt the cookie and understand its content.
   2.1 If apps hosted on the same machine you can use file storage to persist data protection keys:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}")
```

2.2 If the apps hosted on different machines you need to use another type of storage so that both app will be able to access it and read protection keys. For example, you can use [Amazon KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) service with [Amazon.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SSM](https://github.com/aws/aws-ssm-data-protection-provider-for-aspnet) nuget:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToAWSSystemsManager("/MyApplication/DataProtection");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really appreciated. Points 1 & 2 are clear, for your information both applications will share same domain but will be in different subdomains and for point 2 I will put the keys for in shared volume that will be accessible for both apps Docker containers. What is not clear still (I'm still dumb) - the code suggestions you have proposed - where should be applied? In both projects or just in the one who does Authentication (talking about `Startup.cs`)? Do I still need to provide `AddOpenIdConnect` in the second project?

Comment: @user18154574 cookie and data protection settings should be configured in both services. I'm not sure about OIDC config.

Comment: I put some code and error I'm getting, not sure what is the difference between `AddCookie` and `ConfigureApplicationCookie`

Comment: @user18154574 I'm not sure `.localhost` is valid, as `localhost` has special meaning and special handling. There is hidden part before `localhost` in your screenshot, did you add an entry to the `hosts` file to simulate subdomains? I'd recommend using different names for that. But your error is about being unable to unprotect the cookie, meaning unable to find the protection key that was used to encrypt the cookie by service A. And this is because you provided relative path to `PersistKeysToFileSystem` and it's different for A and B. Try using full path.

Comment: Thank you! Saved my life <3 - I had to play with the volumes in Docker and set the full path as you have suggested. Also seems that `ConfigureApplicationCookie` is redundant - not sure about it's purpose. If you have a BuyMeACoffe or some crypto wallet please let me know ;)

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful!