# How to Authenticate two subdomain by one login in IdentityServer?

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I have an IDP server implemented by Duende IdentityServer assume which is hosted on `idp.com` and there are two separate ReactJS applications hosted on `app.mysite.com` and `profile.mysite.com` and they are using JWT token for authentication and authorization process. now when I login into `app.mysite.com` through `idp.com` `profile.mysite.com` is un unauthenticated and needs another login. I use the same client configuration for both of these sites. I know there are some methods such as using an IFRAME inside client code to share the JWT token between these two app but I am looking for a built-in approach inside the Identity server to solve this issue?

Comment: So are the user accounts shared between the two sites or are they separate?

Comment: the user accounts are shared and stored inside the identity server.

Comment: So I guess you don't want to generate one token that covers both services?

Comment: It is not necessary, I just want to authenticate the user once and do not force the user to login separately for each  app

Comment: In your controller action for displaying the login page, you could probably check if the user is already logged on, and update their claims for the new site before redirecting to the return URL.

Comment: Do you mean I should check the login status of the user in idp side? but the application should send some thing to indicate the user ifo to find that status

Comment: I imagine you have a cookie on the IdentityServer side, but the client side code is starting the Authorize flow. My guess is that you can probably still determine if the cookie on the IS side is good, and if it is you can use that information as the basis for automatically authenticating the user. I've never tried this though, so I might be wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to do that with JWT only, but you can store the token in cookie and share it between subdomains. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71613883/c-sharp-how-to-share-authentication-authorization-cookie-between-projects/71616001#71616001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you have 2 CLIENTS, you should configure 2 separate configurations for both of them.

Afer separation of clients you should rely on cookie set on `idp.com` after first authentication. (Good to know - How to setup cookie authentication basic cookie authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Anyway, if you configured IdentityServer properly, it handles cookie authentication "out-of-the-box" - so probably the only thing you have to do is to Signin the user.

```
AuthenticationProperties props = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    IsPersistent = true,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(LoginOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
};

var issuer = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
{
    DisplayName = user.Username
};

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(issuer, props);
```

When the youser want to login to second application, after start of the flow (eg. code flow) and redirect to the `idp.com`, `idp.com` knows that the user is already signed-in (cookie) and should immediately generate token and redirect back to the return url.

If you need you can adjust custom behaviours using `IProfileService`.